# scale_y_discrete ignores breaks/labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Bug? Possibly related [to this..](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1589)

```
dat = data.frame(x = 1:4, y = ordered(c(4,'>5',1,1), levels = c(1:5, '>5')), grp = 1)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + geom_step() + 
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = levels(dat$y), labels = levels(dat$y))
```

[image]

Comment: Does `drop=FALSE` in `scale_y_discrete` do what you want? if not, you'll need to clarify what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + geom_step() + 
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = levels(dat$y), labels = levels(dat$y), drop = FALSE)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Ah, thanks Roland. Would help if that was in the `scale_y_discrete` documentation.

Comment: See the documentation of the ellipses.

Comment: Doesn't that assume a fairly deep knowledge of ggplot?

Comment: If you think so. Obviously, the package authors believe you should be able to follow a link.

Comment: I think I'm missing a critical step in the documentation. What's the obvious link between `scale_y_discrete` and `ellipses`?

Comment: "... common discrete scale parameters: name, breaks, labels, na.value, limits and guide. See discrete_scale for more details"