# Omit axis labels - axis is a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line graph of soccer season league positions at end of season for two teams for every season since 1893. The seasons (in the format 18XX/XX) are a factor. The graph plots every season since 1893/94 on the axis. It's too crowded. Is there any way to omit axis labels?

Ideally I'd like them to mark every decade, so eg, 1900/01, 1910/11.

This is the code:

```
ggplot(Mydata, aes(x = Season, y = value)) + 
geom_line(aes(colour = variable, group = variable)) +
scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
labs(title = "Blades vs Owls. End of season league position since 1892/93",
   x = "Season", y = "League position")
```

The addition of this code fixed it for me:

```
+ scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("1893/94", "1900/01", "1910/11", "1920/21", 
                            "1930/31", "1938/39", "1950/51", "1960/61", 
                            "1970/71", "1980/81", "1990/91", "2000/01", 
                            "2010/11", "2020/21"))
```

Comment: You should probably format the data as dates before plotting

Comment: Alternatively or additionally, you can set `breaks=` (values/locations on the x-axis) and `labels=` (actual text put on the axis) in `scale_*` functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or at least related to) https://stackoverflow.com/q/43088354/3358272

Comment: This might be useful too https://stackoverflow.com/a/50710428/786542